# go-sql-driver/mysql - inserting a float64 into mariadb (double column) gives unsupported type func() float64, a func

Tags: mysql, go

I am new to Go I just started learning it a few days ago for the concurrency :-). I have a different library that returns a time.Duration type, which has Seconds, a float64 precision value I'd like to use and store in a database.

Here are relevant bits and pieces to what I'm trying to accomplish:

```golang
type pResp struct {
    address string
    rtt     time.Duration
    sent    int
    recv    int
}

stmt, err := db.Prepare("insert pings set domain = ?, packet_rtt = ?, packets_sent = ?, packets_recv = ?")
res, err := stmt.Exec(r.address, r.rtt.Seconds, r.sent, r.recv)
```

This is the error I get:

```
2019/08/26 19:57:35 sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type func() float64, a func
Process exiting with code: 0
```

The column in MySQL is set to double, which should be 64 bits... I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Is this a limitation of the library I am using? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are passing a first class function `func() float64` instead of an actual float64 primitive. The source of this function looks to be `r.rtt.Seconds`, which should be invoked as `r.rtt.Seconds()`. See [Duration.Seconds](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Seconds).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now. VSCode did not suggest the ()'s, I was thinking it was a static member of that type/class, so for the life of me I wouldn't have seen this.